# ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column ' ' at row 1

Tags: mysql

When I try to import my table named "Table.csv" to a MYSQl database using the linux console, it shows me the following message, ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'factor' at row 1

This is the description of the contents of the table that I had previously created:

```
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| degrees             | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| percentage          | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| factor              | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is how the data delimited only by commas "," is displayed as it is displayed from a plain text file:

```
1,0.35,1     
2,0.10,3.0787
1,0.55,4.32
```

This is the sentence that I currently enter:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/tabla.csv' INTO TABLE Student FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

In this case, there should be no problem because the table starts with the values from its header, since I have omitted the IGNORE 1 LINES statement;

I enclose the information where I check more questions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 2):

After verifying the way in which the data are structured and how the **CSV** file is stored, the sentence that should be used corresponds to:

LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/table.csv' INTO TABLE Student FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' **OPTIONALLY** ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\ n';

Care should be taken with the type of data, its length and if it has some content, in this case all fields are filled with **NULL**, so they must be replaced by **NOT NULL** fields.